# Is there any test data for Telegram Channel Access Token since I cannot receive the verification code when login?

Tags: azure, botframework, telegram-bot, chatbot, azure-bot-service

Our team is trying to create Telegram Channel. Seems it requires phone verification when login Telegram platform but I cannot receive the verification code after tried many times. So may I ask is there any test data for Telegram Channel Access Token?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are developing your bot. But if you are using Azure Botframework and emulator, you can test authentication as below blog.

https://blog.botframework.com/2018/08/28/testing-authentication-to-your-bot-using-the-bot-framework-emulator/

If you are just asking virtual access token for telegram, I would suggest you to ping at @BotSupport in Telegram to get more information since they have not mentioned any online testing ways with access token.

-Yutong